# Saving JsPsych data from HTML as CSV

Tags: javascript, html, csv, save, jspsych

I've been trying to save a **CSV file** to my local computer, with the data from the HTML experiment that runs from the script, but I only ever end up with a new webpage showing all of the data, when finishing my experiment...I think it is mostly the variables 'var jsPsych' and 'var today' that's the problem. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My experiment</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/jspsych@7.2.3"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@jspsych/plugin-html-keyboard-response@1.1.1"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@jspsych/plugin-survey-multi-choice@1.1.1"></script>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/jspsych@7.2.3/css/jspsych.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body></body>
<script>
/* initialize jsPsych */

/*var jsPsych = initJsPsych();*/
var jsPsych = initJsPsych({
        timeline: timeline,
        show_progress_bar: true,
        override_safe_mode: true,
        on_finish: function() {
            jsPsych.data
                .get()
                .localSave(
                    'csv',
                    'ekstra.html'
                );
        },
    });

var today = new Date();
    jsPsych.data.addProperties({
        date: ("0" + today.getDate()).slice(-2) + '-' + ("0" + (today.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + today.getFullYear(),
        time: today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds(),
    });

/* create timeline */
var timeline = [];

// generate a random subject ID with 15 characters
var subject_id = jsPsych.randomization.randomID(6);

// this adds a property called 'subject' to every trial
jsPsych.data.addProperties({
  subject: subject_id,
});

var time_limit = 10000;
var start_time2;
var end_test_timer;
var trial_count = 0;
var n_trials = 7;
var counter2 = 1;

var sproglyde = {
  type: jsPsychSurveyMultiChoice,
  data: { sproglyde_test: 'Sproglyde' },
  questions: [
  {
      prompt: "<p>Vælg det 'ord' der lyder som et rigtigt dansk ord.</p><p>Vælg ordet (gæt evt.):</p>", 
      name: 'Sproglyd1', 
      options: ['sbese', 'sbuse', 'sbise', 'befse'], 
      required: true
    }, 
    {
      prompt: "Vælg ordet (gæt evt.):", 
      name: 'Sproglyd2', 
      options: ['sigam', 'sigar', 'sigur', 'sigat'], 
      required: true
    },
    {
      prompt: "Vælg ordet (gæt evt.):", 
      name: 'Sproglyd3', 
      options: ['nåmmer', 'nymmer', 'måmmer', 'fåmmer'], 
      required: true
    }
  ],
    on_load: function() {
                trial_count++;
                // we need to set up the timer to end the current timeline after a certain duration, but only on the first trial
                if (trial_count > 0) {
                    start_time2 = performance.now();
                    var end_test_timer = setTimeout(function() {
                        // this stuff is just for testing
                        var end_time = performance.now();
                        var elapsed_time = end_time - start_time2;
                        console.log("elapsed time: ", elapsed_time);
                        // this function ends the current trial 
                        jsPsych.finishTrial({status: "ended early"});
                    }, time_limit);
                }
            }, 
            on_finish: function() {
                counter2++;
                // we also need to cancel the setTimeout timer if the person gets all the way through the timeline before 
                // time_limit is reached, otherwise endCurrentTimeline will fire during the next timeline - not good!!
                if (trial_count == n_trials) {
                    clearTimeout(end_test_timer);
                }
                    }
};
timeline.push(sproglyde);


var Ordforråds = {
  type: jsPsychSurveyMultiChoice,
  data: { ordforraad_test: 'ordforraad' },
  questions: [
    {
      prompt: "<p>Vælg det ord som findes på dansk. Tænk ikke for længe. Du er velkommen til at gætte, hvis du ikke kender svaret</p>", 
      name: 'Ordforråd1', 
      options: ['gis', 'gim', 'git'], 
      required: true
    }, 
    {
      prompt: "Vælg ordet (gæt evt.):", 
      name: 'Ordforråd2', 
      options: ['trokæ', 'troklæ', 'tropæ'], 
      required: true
    }, 
    {
      prompt: "Vælg ordet (gæt evt.):", 
      name: 'Ordforråd3', 
      options: ['tights', 'tigts', 'kights'], 
      required: true
    }
  ],
};
timeline.push(Ordforråds);

/* run the experiment */
jsPsych.run(timeline);

    </script>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Change `jsPsych.data.get().localSave('csv', 'ekstra.html');` to `jsPsych.data.get().localSave('csv', 'ekstra.csv');` (note the extension change from `.html` to `.csv` in the end).

What you are doing is saving the data in `.html` format, not `.csv`.